# How to pass data from child to parent and render content based on selected value in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, swr

I am learning React as I am fetching data from Pokéapi to make a list component, card component, detail component and filter component. I am trying to make a filter so you can filter by pokémon type. Only the cards that also contain that type string should then render (Not there yet). So I am not sure if a) I should make a different call from API inside PokemonList depending on selected value or b) if I should compare the values and just change how the PokemonCard element is rendered inside PokemonList.js depending on the comparison. I managed to pass data from filter to the list component. I have then been trying to pass the type data from PokemonCard.js to the list component so that I can compare these two values but I find it hard to use callbacks to pass the type data from the card component, since I dont pass it through an event or something like that.

[image]

Which method should I use here to simplify the filtering? Make different API call or render PokemonCard element conditionally?
Is it a good idea to compare filter option to pokemon card's type in PokemonList.js? Then how can I pass that data from the card component since I don't pass it through click event?

Thankful for any ideas! I paste the code from list component that contains the cards, card component and filter component.

PokemonList component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import useSWR from 'swr';
import PokemonCard from './PokemonCard';
import PokemonFilter from './PokemonFilter';
import './PokemonList.css';

const PokemonList = () => {

const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const [type, setType] = useState('');

function selectedType(type) { // value from filter dropdown
    setType(type)
    console.log("handled")
    console.log(type)
}

const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=9&offset=${index}`;

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())
const { data: result, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);

if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
if (!result) return <div>loading...</div>

result.results.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1);


return (
    <section>
        <PokemonFilter onSelectedType={selectedType} selectedPokemonType={type} />
        <div className="pokemon-list">
            <div className="pokemons">
                {result.results.map((pokemon) => (
                    <PokemonCard key={pokemon.name} pokemon={pokemon} /> // callback needed??
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className="pagination">
                <button 
                    onClick={() => setIndex(index - 9)} 
                    disabled={result.previous === null}
                >
                Previous
                </button>
                <button 
                    onClick={() => setIndex(index + 9)}
                    disabled={result.next === null}
                >
                Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default PokemonList;
```

PokemonCard component:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import useSWR from 'swr';
import './PokemonCard.css';

const PokemonCard = ({ pokemon }) => {

const { name } = pokemon;

const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`;
const { data, error } = useSWR(url);

if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>

const { types, abilities } = data;

// types[0].type.name <---- value I want to pass to PokemonList.js

return (
        <div className='pokemon-card'>
            <div className='pokemon-card__content'>
                <img
                    className='pokemon-card__image'
                    src={data.sprites.front_default}
                    alt={name}
                />
                <div className='pokemon-card__info'>  
                <p className='pokemon-card__name'>Name: {name}</p>
                <p className='pokemon-card__abilities'>Abilities: {abilities[0].ability.name}</p>
                <p className='pokemon-card__categories'>Category: {types[0].type.name}</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <Link className='pokemon-card__link' to={{
                pathname: `/${name}`,
                state: data
                }}>
                View Details
            </Link>
        </div>
  )
}

export default PokemonCard;
```

PokemonFilter component:

```
import './PokemonFilter.css';
import useSWR from 'swr';

const PokemonFilter = ({onSelectedType, selectedPokemonType}) => {

const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/`;

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json())
const { data: result, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);

if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
if (!result) return <div>loading...</div>

function filteredTypeHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    onSelectedType(e.target.value);
}

console.log(selectedPokemonType)

return(
    <div className="pokemon-types__sidebar">
        <h2>Filter Pokémon by type</h2>
        <select 
            name="pokemon-type" 
            className="pokemon-types__filter"
            onChange={filteredTypeHandler}
            >
            <option value="All">Filter By Type</option>
            {result.results.map((type) => {
            return (
                <option key={type.name} value={type.name}> {type.name}</option>
                )
            })}
        </select>
    </div>
  )
}

export default PokemonFilter;
```

Comment: You should use useEffect. Each time your PokemonFilter component changes (when a category is selected) you will make a callback to the 'fetcher' function and you save the response in a state (an array). Then you use the map() function to display the cards.

Comment: Each time your PokemonFilter component changes => Each time the "type" state changes

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I will try to modify the code like you suggested tomorrow. I’ll get back to you to let you know the result, or if it’s okay to ask for more input.

Comment: @MB_ 
What do you mean by saving the response in a state? I am making separate calls to the API, so which response should I save in a state and how can I combine these two calls so that the list renders depending on the state of type? 
I can't use useSWR inside of useEffect so I am not sure how to combine useEffect with useSWR. Or is the callback you proposed I'd use a solution to that? I am not really following. I also read in SWR docs and saw that I could implement condional fetching. Do you think that could be an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to improve, modify, ... I didn't test, it's just a visual example.

I don't know about `useSWR` sorry, I use `axios` in my example...

If you want to centralize all your API requests, you can create a `useApi` hook, on the internet you will find tutorials.

**PokemonList.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';                           // or swr

import PokemonFilter from './PokemonFilter';
import PokemonCard from './PokemonCard';

export default function PokemonList() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

  // Executed every first render
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  // Executed only when filter changes
  useEffect(() => {
    getDataByTypes(filter);
  }, [filter]);

  // Get data
  const getData = async () => {
    const uri = 'https://xxx';

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(uri);
      setData(response.data...);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Get data by types
  const getDataByTypes = async (filter) => {
    const uri = `https://xxx/type/${filter}...`;

    if (filter) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(uri);
        setData(response.data...);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <PokemonFilter filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="cards-container">
          {data.map((d) => (
            <PokemonCard key={d.name} data={d} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PokemonCard.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function PokemonCard({ data }) {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons(data);
  }, [data]);

  // Get Pokemons
  const getPokemons = async (data) => {
    const uri = `https://xxx/pokemon/${data.name}/`;

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(uri);
      setPokemons(response.data...);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {pokemons && (
        <div className="card">
          <img src={pokemons.sprites.front_default} alt={pokemons.name} />
          <p>{pokemons.name}</p>
          <p>{pokemons.abilities[0].ability.name}</p>
          <p>{pokemons.types[0].type.name}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PokemonFilter.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function PokemonFilter({ filter, setFilter }) {
  const [types, setTypes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getType();
  }, []);

  // Get Type
  const getType = async () => {
    const uri = 'https://xxx/type/';

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(uri);
      setTypes(response.data.results....);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleFilter = (e) => {
    setFilter(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <select onChange={handleFilter} value={filter}>
      <option>Filter by type</option>
      {types.map((type) => {
        return (
          <option key={type.name} value={type.name}>
            {type.name}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to translate this into an answer in code. I had trouble with translating this into SWR so I am currently trying to use Axios instead. Now I get an error once I click a type in the filter, so I am guessing it has to to with the data that hasn't been fetched yet and React is trying to map through it before that. But it seems easier to find a solution to that error than to solve this with SWR, so I will probably keep going with Axios or fetch from now on. :) @MB_